# How to allow access to WAMP Virtual Host from over the internet?

Tags: virtualbox, apache-http-server, localhost

I try to write everything with the settings with all.

I have a localhost with wamp and windows 10, that I'm trying to access from other computers outside the network.
Because i have some problems access the code true localhost virtual I create a new virtual host.

1, I create a new folder in the root called example: folder-1 where i add all the files.

**http-vhost.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# xxxx.dyndns.org
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName xxxx.dyndns.org
  ServerAlias xxxx.dyndns.org
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/folder-1"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/folder-1">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my hosts I add the ip to the virtual host

**Hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost

127.0.0.1 xxxx.dyndns.org
::1 xxxx.dyndns.org
```

because I needed https I search the internet for answer and find a tutorial to add https to wamp.
https://www.proy.info/how-to-enable-localhost-https-on-wamp-server/

and in my **httpd-ssl.conf** i add this :

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/folder-1"
ServerName https://xxxx.dyndns.org:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.46/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.46/logs/access.log"
SSLCertificateFile "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.46/conf/key/certificate.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.46/conf/key/private.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

in my regular **httpd.conf** I have this settings.

```
ServerName localhost:80
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
```

The next step was to inbound in windows defender, I add 2 inbound.
http with port 80 and https port 443

My ip I use is:

192.168.10.xxx that is the router ip it gives me.
85.226.170.xxx is my public ip.

When i access in my network everything works, but when i try outside the network i only get:

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.**

Do I have forget anything.

update:

[image]

My setting from router.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you configured port forwarding on your router? There's really no point in obfuscating private addresses (for example 192.168 -addresses) as they're only used in the intranets, so do not reveal anything special from your network. However knowing accurate internal IPs may be crucial to resolve issues.

Comment: i have setup DynDNS IPV4 in the router, and use dyn/updater

Comment: ... so no? DynDNS is an entirely different ballgame compared to port forwarding, not even in the same ballpark. Your router has a firewall that blocks all new incoming connections. I.e. all attempts to reach your webserver from the internet. To allow access you have to poke holes on the firewall - port 80 to allow `HTTP`-traffic, port 443 for `HTTPS`. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) for general info (you need static port forwarding) and your router's manual to find out how to configure it. Your webserve also needs a static IP.

Comment: I ask my supplier for the internet to make a static IP, that I use to do before. They have removed it and used dyn.com. why I don´t now.

Comment: Sorry but you misunderstood

Comment: Your router's public IP doesn't matter, you can leave it as it is, and leave DynDNS in place. Your virtual machine needs to have NIC configured in Bridge mode so it can have a static IP address on your 192.168.10.0/24 network. You can put that VM:s IP to the DMZ - _not_ the host system's IP. The system that's in the DMZ will not be protected by the router's firewall. Alternatively you don't enable DMZ but create port forwarding rules as described in the router's manual to direct `HTTP`and `HTTPS` traffic to your webserver's IP address.

Comment: The router screenshot says that your service provider has reserved port 443 and you can't configure a port forwarding with that. So your webserver can't be reached with `https://servername` - that's traffic on port 443. You need to use another, arbitrary portnumber for `HTTPS`traffic, like 44300. I don't know how to do that with DynDNS. `http://servername` can be forwarded from your router without problems; that's port 80. It seems you don't entirely understand the concepts involved, so it's hard to do this online. You should ask help from a friend who knows a bit more about this.

Comment: I add port forward  to port 44300 and point it to the server, still forbidden, my be I should change server Name, use ip instead of xxxx.dyndns.com, my be that's the problem.

Comment: Using IP instead of DNS name is definitely the first step of troubleshooting. It needs to work for DNS to work. I'd again suggest you ask help from someone who is more familiar with the concepts involved here. As long as we can't see what exactly you have done it's not possible to really help online.